# Create a CSS that give the similar result like browser highlight

Tags: css

I am trying to create a css style that give the same result like native browser highlight so i can put in the css into tinymce.
but from the photo below you can see that the height of the custom css is too low, i tried a few method like using display:inline-block, it works fine for the height but it automatically remove the first and the last space.

Any expert please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
.highlight {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: .5em 0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/c7rdekej/

Comment: ur solution didn't solve the problem. what i want is that the height should follow the most taller word in that line, i doubt if css can do that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a span around the text you want to highlight and assign a class to it
like `highlight`

And add css property like below

```
.highlight {
    background:#008AE6;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Check this fiddle for clarification http://jsfiddle.net/5u52qw57/

Let me know if it is helpful

Comment: for sure it won't be so straight forward.

Comment: i was trying to make the height exactly as tall as the browser native highlight.

Comment: Yeah check the fiddle above. height of the highlighted part is as same as the native highlight. You can comapre it by selecting nearest text (in our case "is too low") of the highlighted text you can see there is no difference in that